# CMAKE Build error while building cppyy from source

Tags: cmake, build, cppyy

I am trying to build cppyy from source, following the strps mentiond in the [documentation](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/repositories.html).

While compiling cppyy-cling, using `$ python -m pip install . --upgrade` as mentiond in the docs, I am getting the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cppyy-cling
  Building wheel for cppyy-cling (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

The full error is:

```
    × Building wheel for cppyy-cling (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3136 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_get_cppflags.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/bindings_utils.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/loader.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_cling_config.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_cppyy_generator.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_genreflex.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_version.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/_rootcling.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      copying python/cppyy_backend/__init__.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend
      creating build/lib/cppyy_backend/cmake
      copying python/cppyy_backend/cmake/FindCppyy.cmake -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/cmake
      copying python/cppyy_backend/cmake/FindLibClang.cmake -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/cmake
      creating build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/__init__.py.in -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/MANIFEST.in.in -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/setup.py.in -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/test_bindings.py.in -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/setup.cfg.in -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      copying python/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates/initializor.py -> build/lib/cppyy_backend/pkg_templates
      Now building cppyy-cling
      Creating build directory /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/builddir ...
      Running cmake for cppyy-cling: cmake /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20 -DLLVM_ENABLE_TERMINFO=0 -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=0 -Dminimal=ON -Dbuiltin_cling=ON -Druntime_cxxmodules=OFF -Dbuiltin_zlib=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/builddir/install/cppyy_backend
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.43.0")
      -- Looking for python ...
      -- Found Python: /usr/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.7") found components: Interpreter
      -- ROOT default compression algorithm: zlib
      -- Found GCC. Major version 13, minor version 2
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      -- Found a 64bit system
      -- Found GNU compiler collection
      -- Performing Test GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
      -- Performing Test GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI - Success
      -- Build Platform: linux
      -- Build Compiler: GNU 13.2.0
      -- Build Processor: x86_64
      -- Build Architecture: linuxx8664gcc
      -- Build Type: 'RelWithDebInfo' (flags = '-O2 -g -DNDEBUG')
      -- Compiler Flags:  -std=c++20 -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-noexcept-type -pipe  -Wshadow -Wall -W -Woverloaded-virtual -fsigned-char -pthread -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
      -- Binutils as version: 2.42
      -- Performing Test SSE_FLAG
      -- Performing Test SSE_FLAG - Success
      -- Performing Test SSE_COMPILATION
      -- Performing Test SSE_COMPILATION - Success
      -- Performing Test SSE_RUN
      -- Performing Test SSE_RUN - Success
      -- Performing Test AVX2_FLAG
      -- Performing Test AVX2_FLAG - Success
      -- Performing Test AVX2_COMPILATION
      -- Performing Test AVX2_COMPILATION - Failed
      -- Performing Test AVX2_RUN
      -- Performing Test AVX2_RUN - Failed
      -- Performing Test ROOT_HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB
      -- Performing Test ROOT_HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
      -- Building LLVM in 'Release' mode.
      -- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
      -- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
      -- clang project is enabled
      -- clang-tools-extra project is disabled
      -- compiler-rt project is disabled
      -- cross-project-tests project is disabled
      -- libc project is disabled
      -- libclc project is disabled
      -- libcxx project is disabled
      -- libcxxabi project is disabled
      -- libunwind project is disabled
      -- lld project is disabled
      -- lldb project is disabled
      -- mlir project is disabled
      -- openmp project is disabled
      -- parallel-libs project is disabled
      -- polly project is disabled
      -- pstl project is disabled
      -- flang project is disabled
      -- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.14")
      -- Looking for backtrace
      -- Looking for backtrace - found
      -- backtrace facility detected in default set of libraries
      -- Found Backtrace: /usr/include
      -- Native target architecture is X86
      -- Threads disabled.
      -- Doxygen disabled.
      -- Go bindings disabled.
      -- Could NOT find OCaml (missing: OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
      -- OCaml bindings disabled.
      -- Could NOT find Python module pygments
      -- Could NOT find Python module pygments.lexers.c_cpp
      -- Could NOT find Python module yaml
      -- LLVM host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
      -- LLVM default target triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
      -- Building with -fPIC
      -- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.10 (found suitable version "3.10.7", minimum required is "3.0") found components: Interpreter
      -- Linker detection: GNU ld
      -- Targeting X86
      -- Targeting NVPTX
      -- Clang version: 13.0.0
      -- Not building amdgpu-arch: hsa-runtime64 not found
      -- Building Cling as part of ROOT
      -- Cling version (from VERSION file): ROOT_1.0~dev
      -- Cling will look for C++ headers in '/usr/include/c++/13:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13:/usr/include/c++/13/backward' at runtime.
      -- And then fallback to: 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-13'
      -- Performing Test CXX_HAS_Wno_maybe_uninitialized
      -- Performing Test CXX_HAS_Wno_maybe_uninitialized - Success
      -- Performing Test __result
      -- Performing Test __result - Success
      -- Performing Test CXX_HAS_fno_rtti
      -- Performing Test CXX_HAS_fno_rtti - Success
      -- Performing Test found_setresuid
      -- Performing Test found_setresuid - Success
      -- Performing Test found_stdstringview
      -- Performing Test found_stdstringview - Success
      -- Performing Test found_stod_stringview
      -- Performing Test found_stod_stringview - Failed
      -- Performing Test found_opplusequal_stringview
      -- Performing Test found_opplusequal_stringview - Success
      -- Performing Test found_stdapply
      -- Performing Test found_stdapply - Success
      -- Performing Test found_stdinvoke
      -- Performing Test found_stdinvoke - Success
      -- Performing Test found_stdindexsequence
      -- Performing Test found_stdindexsequence - Success
      -- Performing Test found_attribute_always_inline
      -- Performing Test found_attribute_always_inline - Success
      -- Performing Test has_found_attribute_noinline
      -- Performing Test has_found_attribute_noinline - Success
      Running /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/build/unix/compiledata.sh
      Making /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/builddir/include/compiledata.h
      -- Configuring done (15.1s)
      -- Generating done (1.3s)
      -- Build files have been written to: /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/builddir
      Now building cppyy-cling and dependencies ...
      [  0%] Copying header /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/io/io/inc/TBufferFile.h to /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/builddir/include
      .
      .
      .
      [ 10%] Building CXX object core/meta/CMakeFiles/Meta.dir/src/TEnum.cxx.o
      [ 10%] Building CXX object core/textinput/CMakeFiles/TextInput.dir/src/textinput/Editor.cpp.o
      In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_iterator.h:85,
                       from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                       from /usr/include/c++/13/deque:62,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/textinput/src/textinput/Editor.h:18,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/textinput/src/textinput/Editor.cpp:16:
      In function ‘constexpr void std::_Construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = char; _Args = {}]’,
          inlined from ‘static constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<true>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = char*; _Size = long unsigned int]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:666:23,
          inlined from ‘static constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<true>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = char*; _Size = long unsigned int]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:660:9,
          inlined from ‘constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = char*; _Size = long unsigned int]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:712:20,
          inlined from ‘constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = char*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = char]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:779:44,
          inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/vector.tcc:668:41,
          inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_vector.h:1013:21,
          inlined from ‘textinput::Text& textinput::Text::operator=(const std::string&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/textinput/src/textinput/Text.h:76:20:
      /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_construct.h:119:7: warning: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
        119 |       ::new((void*)__p) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
            |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                       from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/allocator.h:46,
                       from /usr/include/c++/13/deque:63:
      In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*) [with _Tp = char]’,
          inlined from ‘constexpr _Tp* std::allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = char]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/allocator.h:198:40,
          inlined from ‘static constexpr _Tp* std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Up> >::allocate(allocator_type&, size_type) [with _Tp = char]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:28,
          inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_vector.h:378:33,
          inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_vector.h:375:7,
          inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/vector.tcc:663:45,
          inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_vector.h:1013:21,
          inlined from ‘textinput::Text& textinput::Text::operator=(const std::string&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/textinput/src/textinput/Text.h:76:20:
      /usr/include/c++/13/bits/new_allocator.h:147:55: note: destination object of size 0 allocated by ‘operator new’
        147 |         return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
            |                                                       ^
      [ 10%] Building CXX object core/meta/CMakeFiles/Meta.dir/src/TEnumConstant.cxx.o
      [ 10%] Building CXX object core/textinput/CMakeFiles/TextInput.dir/src/textinput/History.cpp.o
      [ 10%] Building CXX object interpreter/llvm-project/llvm/utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenTarget.cpp.o
      .
      .
      [ 97%] Building CXX object core/dictgen/CMakeFiles/Dictgen.dir/src/ClassSelectionRule.cxx.o
      In file included from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/Decl.h:21,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:19,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/metacling/src/TClingBaseClassInfo.h:30,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/metacling/src/TClingBaseClassInfo.cxx:23:
      In member function ‘T* clang::LazyOffsetPtr<T, OffsT, Get>::get(clang::ExternalASTSource*) const [with T = clang::CXXBaseSpecifier; OffsT = long unsigned int; T* (clang::ExternalASTSource::* Get)(OffsT) = &clang::ExternalASTSource::GetExternalCXXBaseSpecifiers]’,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:341:25,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:339:23,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:598:73,
          inlined from ‘CppyyLegacy::TClingBaseClassInfo::TClingBaseClassInfo(cling::Interpreter*, CppyyLegacy::TClingClassInfo*)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/metacling/src/TClingBaseClassInfo.cxx:86:31:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

          inlined from ‘clang::CXXRecordDecl::base_class_range clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases()’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:591:12,
          inlined from ‘bool clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<Derived>::TraverseCXXRecordHelper(clang::CXXRecordDecl*) [with Derived = CppyyLegacy::RScanner]’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h:1897:34:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
.
.
.
.
      gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:28121: core/dictgen/CMakeFiles/Dictgen.dir/all] Error 2
      In file included from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/Decl.h:21,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ASTContext.h:22,
                       from /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/clingutils/src/TClingUtils.cxx:35:
      In member function ‘T* clang::LazyOffsetPtr<T, OffsT, Get>::get(clang::ExternalASTSource*) const [with T = clang::CXXBaseSpecifier; OffsT = long unsigned int; T* (clang::ExternalASTSource::* Get)(OffsT) = &clang::ExternalASTSource::GetExternalCXXBaseSpecifiers]’,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:341:25,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:339:23,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:598:73,
          inlined from ‘void CppyyLegacy::TMetaUtils::WritePointersSTL(const AnnotatedRecordDecl&, const cling::Interpreter&, const TNormalizedCtxt&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/clingutils/src/TClingUtils.cxx:2148:80:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      In member function ‘T* clang::LazyOffsetPtr<T, OffsT, Get>::get(clang::ExternalASTSource*) const [with T = clang::CXXBaseSpecifier; OffsT = long unsigned int; T* (clang::ExternalASTSource::* Get)(OffsT) = &clang::ExternalASTSource::GetExternalCXXBaseSpecifiers]’,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:341:25,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:339:23,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:598:73,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_end() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:601:23,
          inlined from ‘void CppyyLegacy::TMetaUtils::WritePointersSTL(const AnnotatedRecordDecl&, const cling::Interpreter&, const TNormalizedCtxt&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/clingutils/src/TClingUtils.cxx:2148:105:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      In member function ‘T* clang::LazyOffsetPtr<T, OffsT, Get>::get(clang::ExternalASTSource*) const [with T = clang::CXXBaseSpecifier; OffsT = long unsigned int; T* (clang::ExternalASTSource::* Get)(OffsT) = &clang::ExternalASTSource::GetExternalCXXBaseSpecifiers]’,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:341:25,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:339:23,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:598:73,
          inlined from ‘void CppyyLegacy::TMetaUtils::CreateNameTypeMap(const clang::CXXRecordDecl&, CppyyLegacy::MembersTypeMap_t&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/clingutils/src/TClingUtils.cxx:1265:77:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      In member function ‘T* clang::LazyOffsetPtr<T, OffsT, Get>::get(clang::ExternalASTSource*) const [with T = clang::CXXBaseSpecifier; OffsT = long unsigned int; T* (clang::ExternalASTSource::* Get)(OffsT) = &clang::ExternalASTSource::GetExternalCXXBaseSpecifiers]’,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:341:25,
          inlined from ‘clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::DefinitionData::getBases() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:339:23,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:598:73,
          inlined from ‘const clang::CXXBaseSpecifier* clang::CXXRecordDecl::bases_end() const’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclCXX.h:601:23,
          inlined from ‘void CppyyLegacy::TMetaUtils::CreateNameTypeMap(const clang::CXXRecordDecl&, CppyyLegacy::MembersTypeMap_t&)’ at /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/core/clingutils/src/TClingUtils.cxx:1265:99:
      /home/kali/Desktop/cppyy-backend/cling/src/interpreter/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/AST/ExternalASTSource.h:378:54: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
        378 |       Ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>((Source->*Get)(Ptr >> 1));
            |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      [ 97%] Built target ClingUtils
      gmake: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
      error: Failed to build cppyy-cling
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cppyy-cling
Failed to build cppyy-cling                                                                                                                                  
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cppyy-cling, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have no idea what I am missing, I pulled the latest code from github, upgraded the packages on my system. Note that I am running Kali Linux on a VM in Windows. I previously tried doing it on windows only, but that provided another set of errors.

Comment: It looks like the install scripts don't like being in a directory with parentheses in the name. Change the name of the `CERN-HSF(Cppyy)` directory to something simpler.

Comment: Hi @AlexReinking that, helped, but Now I am facing a new set of errors.